# Is there a way to split K-Means clusters more horizontally if the clusters formed are more vertical in shape?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using K-means clustering to see similar data points.
The data is normalized with its mean and when I scatter plot the clusters, this is what I get:

These are the clusters formed with k=10
[image: These are the clusters formed with k=10]

Is there a way to get 'tighter' clusters not by just increasing the number of clusters? By 'tighter' clusters, I mean I prefer these clusters in the above image cut more horizontally.

These are the clusters formed with k=15
[image: These are the clusters formed with k=15]

my code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
k = 15
Cluster = KMeans(n_clusters=k, init='k-means++', max_iter=400, n_init=10, random_state=123)
y_pred = Cluster.fit_predict(normalized_df)
label = np.unique(y_pred)
centroids = Cluster.cluster_centers_
```

Comment: No, but you could try usings GMMs as they can "stretch out"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works.